# c# / vb.net webbrowser get htmlelement position

Tags: c#, javascript, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I am trying to get position of html elements in a .net's webbrowser control and failing, 
i need the exact position of the element relative to the whole document or the webbrowser control to be able to send a mouse click using SendMessage() P/Invoke ..

I have tried the solution from here but it didn't work:
[getting absolute position of HTML element in webbrowser control with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954636/getting-absolute-position-of-html-element-in-webbrowser-control-with-c-sharp)

I am guessing that is because the page relies on very complex ajax and css.

the function "WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementFromPoint()" works just fine in getting the accurate html element, i just need the opposite of it.

other wise, should i just keep on searching using "GetElementFromPoint()" until getting the correct element ???

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I am unable to comment on your question, I'll go for making an "answer", even though it won't be much of one...

- What's wrong with clicking the element via JavaScript / [InvokeMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t9yb2z4.aspx)?
- You could also modify the CSS for the element, making it cover the
  whole of the viewport, allowing you to click anywhere within the web
  browser control's viewport.

If you were to post reasons why the solution from your link was unable to work, then it would be <strike>easier</strike> possible to give you a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may get the same exact behaviour by simply doing something like this:

```
public void ClickHtmlElement(WebBrowser o, string htmlElementId)
{
  const string mask = @"javascript:void(document.getElementById('{0}').click())";
  string url = string.Format(mask, htmlElementId);
  o.Navigate(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this exact same issue.  Invoke, .domelement.click(), .click etc... doesn't work, sendmessage does work, but that requires the exact X,Y position.

The only solution I have at the moment is horrible. Basically using GetElementFromPoint(), but instead of going point by point, you can use a step of the width and height of your element.

So if your element is 500 pixels high and 500 pixels wide, then you can search point 0,500,1000,1500 etc.

I've found some jQuery code that shows how complex it actually is to get the correct X,Y position:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/offset.js

I can't believe there isn't an easier way :-(