# C# Get HtmlInputText Offset Position

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, position, html-input

i've found many tips and code for retrieve offset in a web page of a control server side.
But i have problem with

server side i've tried to search in htmlinputtext methods but nothing...

i've tried the code present in [this post of stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954636/getting-absolute-position-of-html-element-in-webbrowser-control-with-c-sharp)
but i can't convert a htmlinputtext to a htmlelement

do you have any suggestions?
thank you very much

Comment: HtmlElement is a windows forms control, which is used when you embed a browser control in a windows form. An HtmlInputText is an ASP.NET control. On your submit button, use OnClientClick to call a javscript function that gets the X,Y position of the control and then set those values into a hidden html element. You will be able to get at the hidden form elements from the code behind.

Comment: thank for your suggestion! i'll try to put this information in a hidden html element at load of page.

Comment: That would work nicely. I'd recommend when the page is posted back to the server because if someone resizes the window, the X,Y might change. On post back, that's the only time you really know for sure what the X,Y is.